# Visual Studio C# Project Reference not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reference

I created a solution in VS with two projects, one "Core" is a class library project, the other is my app project. I added a class NumberUtil (uses namespace Core.Util) and want to reference it in the app project so I choose r-click, add ref... pick Projects and add my Core project as a reference. The ref to Core appears under References in the project explorer but if I try to use the NumberUtil in a class in my app project it can't find it.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I'm not new to programming but new to VS and C#.

Comment: Have you explicitly marked the class as `public`? As in `public class NumberUtil`? If not and you only have it as `class NumberUtil`, then it's marked as `internal` which would make it inaccessible outside of its own project.

Comment: The NumberUtil class in the Core.Util project has to be public and you have to use either the full name of the class including the namespace like 'Core.Util.NumberUtil' or the better way is to add a using on top of the codefile where you want to use the class like 'using Core.Util;'

Comment: you can't access only one class or any class in that library?

Comment: What do you mean with App-Project? Are you developing a Windows Store App?

Comment: No, App project I just write in relation to the library project. One is a reusable library, the other are app. The public scope was missing from the class, doh~! Thanks for pointing this out! It feels strange that VS doesn't automatically add 'imports' when using auto-complete (like Eclipse does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the `using Core.Util` instruction? Normally when you try to use the class, the VS will propose the `using` instruction for you. You can also click on the code where the error is and press alt+shift+F10.